# Representing independent rediscoveries of a result in a survey paper

Tags: citations, review-articles

How to deal with multiple rediscoveries of the same result in a survey paper? The authors are seemingly unaware of each other. The first discovery is more than a decade old, yet people keep reproducing it. Do I only mention the first discovery, or do I also list subsequent ones? I do not want to cross anyone. The survey is part of an effort to build connections within the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, the goal of a survey paper is to make people aware of what other groups / communities are doing and bringing them together. It would be useful to present the full history of discovery and following re-discoveries, development, alternative approaches, etc.